# Display Image in label in ASP.Net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an empty label when i try to display image from my computer to this label 
this is the code :

```
Label1.Text += " " + "<img src='C:/Users/AA/Documents/Bureau/car/img/image3.jpg'>";
```

Comment: just add img tag infront of label

Comment: A side note: website is going to be published on a web server the URL which you are mentioning in your `src` attribute may no longer be valid.

Answer (score 2):

Include image in your project for example if you include in images folder. Following code will for you.

```
Label1.Text += "<img src='images/image3.jpg'></img>";
```

If you want to open it from same path try this

```
Label1.Text += " " + "<img src='file://C:/Users/AA/Documents/Bureau/car/img/image3.jpg'>";
```

Note: file://C:/Users/AA/Documents/Bureau/car/img/image3.jpg will be loaded in IE but not in Chrome or Firefox because loading files form direct path is considered security thread in Chrome and Firefox.

Considering all this i will suggest you to put images in Image and access them from there is simplest way to do it.

Comment: I have trying to use your methode and have not displayed  and  i have one idea to use File Upload like this Label1.Text += " " + "<img alt='' src='"+FileUpload1.FileName+"'/>"; but the image has not display  what is the solution

Comment: See what I am saying is just 1) Add a new folder in your solution. 2) Name that folder Images 3) Add your image image3.jpg in that folder 4) add Label1.Text += "<img src='Images/image3.jpg'></img>";  in u r code

Comment: It's work but i would like to load the image using Upload File because i will retreive the filename from database that was already added with Upload File or i can't use that with google chrome?

Comment: You can access image in any browser once that is uploaded on server. You just need to construct dynamic address for that.

Comment: Yes i have done like that Filename return the name of image and i have concatenate the img folder with the name of my image to insert in the database like that its my objectif is not very simple like the first time  : string query = "INSERT INTO Imagee (ReF_Voiture,cheminImg) Values(" + "2" + ",'" + "img/" + FileUpload1.FileName + "" + "')"; thank you very mush sir

Comment: @JohnLow Great to know it is working for you, as you are giving dynamic address it will work on any browser.

Comment: i have a final question the answer will be yes or no that we can display the image in label using <img ... ></img> in Winform Application ? my objectif for using label and not picture box is to concatenate more images like asp.net and thank you !

Comment: Thank you but HTML We can also write it in Winform application example like export a list of data using html

Comment: Try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.image(v=vs.110).aspx). This may work work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I missed that it's ASP.net

You'll probably want to use Server.MapPath("~/image.jpg") stuff to be relative to deployment location. And close the  tag.

Comment: I guess he is talking about asp.net website

Comment: I will display not only image I will display more image  for this way i choose label for concatenate images

Comment: You're right. The reason it does not display it because the src url is invalid. Use the file:/// scheme if it's a localhost website, but you'll probably want to use Server.MapPath("~/image.jpg") stuff to be relative to deployment location.

Answer (score 0):

This is working example in asp .net c#.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

Label1.Text = "<img alt='' src='images/download-img.jpg' />";
```